# android new task and activity stack issue

Tags: android, android-intent, activity-stack

1. I have my launcher activity (A) set to "singleTop".
2. Now there is something in notification bar. User clicks on it. So I start activity in receiver with

   Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
3. So A's onNewIntent is invoked and I start activity C based on extras in intent.
4. User go back to A(back key)  and to other activity D. And then home key.
5. Now when I long press home. And relaunch my application and step 3 repeats. and user goes to C. where actually user should have gone to D

Answer (score 0):

Somehow , when you press Long home and restart the activity , the extras parameters are lost.Only the data parameter is preserved.

Answer (score 0):

Add `android:launchMode="singleInstance"` in Activity D (in the menifest file). And then check the app behaviour.